# error build: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available' in XCode 14

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using `stripe/react-native-stripe` but when I am heading to create an iOS build. It gave me the error `Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'`. I want to resolve this issue, Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: That is not a simple issue to resolve. It would ideally require an update to the dependency. You could fork and do this yourself, however it would probably be better if the dependency maintainer did the fix. There is currently a closed issue on their github that relates to this https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1144

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Use the update package version for stripe/react-native-stripe
> The Stripe React Native SDK requires Xcode 13.2.1 or later and is
> compatible with apps targeting iOS 12 or above.

> then change the platform :ios 11.0. to 12.0 in podfile
>
> and update Post_install with

```
post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

> and run pod update and pod install command
> hope so this solution work from your side